NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available
I've upgraded Spring Boot from version 1.4.x to 1.5.x. This migration also requires updating other dependencies used in the project, such as migrating Spring Data Commons to version 1.13.x and Spring Data Cassandra to version 1.5.x
This is my CassandraConfig class :
public class CassandraConfiguration implements BeanClassLoaderAware {

    private Cluster cluster;
    private ClassLoader beanClassLoader;
    private ConfigProperties configProperties;

    @Inject
    public void setConfigProperties(ConfigProperties configProperties) {
        this.configProperties = configProperties;
    }

    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return configProperties.getKeyspaceName();
    }

    @Inject
    public void setCluster(Cluster cluster) {
        this.cluster = cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();

        session.setCluster(cluster);
        session.setConverter(cassandraConverter());
        session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
        session.setSchemaAction(getSchemaAction());
        session.setStartupScripts(getStartupScripts());
        session.setShutdownScripts(getShutdownScripts());

        return session;
    }

    protected List<String> getStartupScripts() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    protected List<String> getShutdownScripts() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public CassandraMappingContext cassandraMapping() throws ClassNotFoundException {

        BasicCassandraMappingContext mappingContext = new BasicCassandraMappingContext();

        mappingContext.setBeanClassLoader(beanClassLoader);
        mappingContext.setInitialEntitySet(CassandraEntityClassScanner.scan(getEntityBasePackages()));

        return mappingContext;
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public CassandraConverter cassandraConverter() throws Exception {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(cassandraMapping());
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public CassandraAdminTemplate cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session().getObject(), cassandraConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.beanClassLoader = classLoader;
    }

    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[]{CBilling.class.getPackage().getName()};
    }


    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.NONE;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean<CassandraBillingRepository, CBilling, MapId> cassandraBillingRepositoryFactoryBean() throws Exception {
        CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean<CassandraBillingRepository, CBilling, MapId> factoryBean =
            new CassandraRepositoryFactoryBean<>(CassandraBillingRepository.class);
        factoryBean.setCassandraTemplate(cassandraTemplate());
        factoryBean.setBeanClassLoader(beanClassLoader);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}

This is my service:
@Service
public class AccessEvaluatorService {

    private EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Inject
    public void setEntityRepository(EntityRepository entityRepository) {
        this.entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }
}


This is my repository :
@Repository
public interface EntityRepository extends CustomRepository<EEntity, Long> {}

However, the app fails to load with the following error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setEntityRepository in AccessEvaluatorService required a bean named 'cassandraTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'cassandraTemplate' in your configuration.


When I run the Spring project, I encounter an error related to 'cassandraTemplate', whereas I didn't encounter this type of error with Spring Boot 1.4.x and Spring Data Cassandra 1.4.x.
Do you have any suggestions for resolving this issue?
Thanks in advance
I checked the project configuration, and the dependency versions are compatible with Spring Boot 1.5.x. However, I didn't understand why this problem with the 'cassandraTemplate' bean arises.
